# Lang's definition of generated subring (?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition

> Let $A$ be a subring of a ring $B$. Let $S$ be a subset of $B$
> commuting with $A$; in other words we have $as=sa$ for all $a\in A$
> and $s\in S$. We denote by $A[S]$ the set of all elements $$\sum
>  a_{i_1\ldots i_n}s_1^{i_1}\ldots s_n^{i_n}$$ the sum ranging over
> finite number of $n$-tuples $(i_1,\ldots i_n)$ of integers $\geq0$, and
> $a_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}\in A$, $s_1,\ldots,s_n\in S$.

How can I describe this set in terms of the set-builder notation? (What is this set called? I don't think "generated subring" is correct.)

Comment: Serge Lang has the highest reputation in the community. This definition is correct. What is set-builder notation?

Comment: What part of the definition is unclear? You can wrap the text around braces if you want, but it's a perfectly reasonable definition as it stands.

Comment: @anomaly It is unclear how one can systematically define the $a_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}$'s.

Comment: What is $A[S]$ generally called?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. They're just arbitrary elements of $A$, indexed by the $(i_1, \dots, i_n)$.

Comment: Serge Lang's reputation is certainly not owed to thoroughness or readability. This particular definition is correct, but I would expect some more detail from a textbook.

Comment: A reviewer of one of Lang's books once said that any of Lang's books make every other book in their field look like a major pedagogical advance. Having said that, I learned algebra from Lang's Algebra. He may have been terse in some places, but part of the learning is digging into the meaning of what the author is writing. Active engagement with the subject was necessary, but eventually paid off in understanding. In a similar vein, Herstein once said its important not to say everything so the students have something to ask questions on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition is indeed confusing, even as it can be interpreted correctly. The notation $a_{i_1\ldots i_n}$ suggests that the coefficient in front of $s_1^{i_1} \cdots s_n^{i_n}$  depends only on the exponents $i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n$ but not on the elements $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n$; this is not the case. @QiaochuYuan's suggested formalization does not improve this.

There is a perfectly good way to rewrite the definition in a cleaner form if one takes the time to actually try (which Lang doesn't seem to have done). The key is to proceed in several steps:

- Define an *$S$-monomial* to be a product of finitely many elements of $S$. (This includes the empty product $1$.)
- If $U$ is a subset of $B$, then define a *left $A$-linear combination of elements of $U$* to be an element of the form $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i u_i$, where $k$ is a nonnegative integer and where $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k \in A$ and $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_k \in U$.
- Define $A\left[S\right]$ to be the set of all left $A$-linear combination of $S$-monomials.

Note that the only purpose of the word "left" here is generality; in our specific case, it does not matter whether we put the factors on the left or on the right, since every element of $A$ commutes with every element of $S$ and thus (by induction) also with every $S$-monomial.

Comment: Indeed... and this is a worthwhile exercise to do once in one's life, at least. But, still, to me, the extravagance of the effort seems to give a back-handed proof that this does not explain the _function_ of the thing, by any means. Yes, by now, I do have objections to very many set-theoretic constructions which obscure the intention. Like the notion that an ordered pair in set-theoretic terms is $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. Yes, nice to know that this set-theoretic "definition" is possible... but it's not operationally useful.

Comment: @paulgarrett It's a different definition serving a different purpose. It gives a spanning set; it clears up any issues of size and self-referentiality; it lets you directly check properties (e.g., that $A\left[S\right]$ is commutative if the elements of $A$ and $S$ commute). It's a lot more useful than the set-theoretic definition of ordered pairs.

Comment: Well, to tell what "monomials" are, and to assert that they _span_, certainly can be useful, as in tensor products. In the case of tensor products, we do not attempt to universally describe the _relations_ (Tor, etc.), but we can still characterize maps out of the tensor product. At this moment it's not clear to me that the monomials in $A[S]$ serve an analogous purpose. In any case, different people do have different purposes, and different criteria for utility. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what your objection to this definition is; it's a fine definition and it indeed defines the subring of $B$ generated by $A$ and $S$. It's common, for example, to use notation such as $k[x^2, x^3]$ to denote the subring of $k[x]$ generated by $k$ and $x^2, x^3$. An equivalent definition (this requires a bit of proof) is

$$A[S] = \bigcap_{A \subseteq C \subseteq B, S \subseteq C} C$$

or in words, $A[S]$ is the intersection of all subrings of $B$ containing both $A$ and $S$. In set-builder notation we just have

$$A[S] = \{ b \in B : \exists i_1, i_2, \dots i_n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}, a_{i_1 \dots i_n} \in A, s_i \in S \text{ s.t. } b = \sum a_{i_1 \dots i_n} \prod s_j^{i_j} \}$$

which is just the same thing but with a bunch of quantifiers. Is it clearer now? Note that we need the elements of $S$ to commute with $A$ to guarantee that this subset is closed under multiplication as written.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was hoping to use the multi-index notation. Would something like the following also work? $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbf{N}}\{y\ |\ (\exists a)(\exists s)(a\in A^{\mathbf{N}^n}\land s\in S^n\land y=\sum_{i\in\mathbf{N}^n}a_i s^i)\}$, where $s^i:=\prod_{j=1}^n s_j^{i_j}$ for $s\in S^n$ and $i\in\mathbf{N}^n$.

Comment: I don't think the set-builder is quite right because it fixes the $i_j$ and $s_j$ at the start so the ``sum'' would be over just one element (and also implicitly fixes $n$). Stuffing all the necessary quantifiers in there will make things dramatically messier. It's more like "those $b$ such that there exists an $n$, exist finitely many $n$-tuples $i$, finitely many $n$-tuples $s$ for each $i$, a coefficient $a_{i,s}$ for each choice of tuple and values $s$ such that $b = \sum_i \sum_{s} a_{i,s} \prod_j s_j^{i_j}$" or some awful thing like that.

Comment: @alf262: you need to specify that $a$ has finite support but otherwise that's fine, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that there is a completely accepted/acceptable tradition of saying things like "all expressions... of lengths $n$, for variable $n$...", and/or "anything expressible as...", there is potential ambiguity here, or at least a requirement of some cooperation from the reader, I think. :)  That's not necessarily a bad thing, but, while we may argue that this style of "definition" is fairly intuitive for many of us, it can be criticized.

In the example at hand, with rings $A\subset B$ and $S\subset C$, a formally very clear, but intuitively murky, definition of $A[S]$, "the subring of $B$ generated by $A$ and $S$", is as the intersection of all subrings of $B$ which contain both $A$ and $S$. No comment about what sort of expressions appear, nor necessarily any comment about whether elements of $S$ need commute with elements of $A$. It is perfectly well-defined, though.

Note that there was no mandate to have two things, $A$ and $S$. It would have sufficed to take any subseet $A\cup S$. The details do affect the expressibility.

A better-known analogue that has the same features is "subgroup $\langle S\rangle$ of group $G$ generated by $S\subset G$". It is perhaps most intuitive to say that this subgroup is the collection of all "words" involving elements of $S$ and their inverses. There is a minor notational/philosophical issue of what "words" are... Then one has to prove that this is a subgroup. Oppositely, the subgroup can be characterized as the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ containing the subset $S$. This characterization removes ambiguity and dependence on notation...

Comment: This is indeed a definition of $A\left[S\right]$, but not the one the OP wants to understand.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I know, but, as I guess I should have said, there's not necessarily much point in formalizing a suggestive but imprecise idea... though, sure, maybe it's a reasonable exercise. But that was the kind of exercise (which, yes, I did do many of) whose main point turned out to be that it had been a waste of time. :) Tastes vary! :)